# Cyber punk(?) detective novel with a cat thing as a "pet"?

Tags: story-identification, books, cyberpunk, steampunk, detective

I read this a couple years ago and it’s driving me crazy trying to remember. Futuristic detective novel where he has a semi pet called a cat thing(?) she is attracted to shiny things and he is always buying them for her but she quickly loses interest. One thing I remember him buying her was a shiny g string which she tied on her wrist. steam punk? cyberpunk?